# writing to text file using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, binaryfiles

my problem is to read non primes from txt file and write prime factors in same file.
i actually dont know how BufferedReader works.from my understanding i am trying to read the file data to buffer(8kb) and write prime factors to file.(by creating a new one)

```
    class  PS_Task2               
     {   
     public static void main(String[] args)     
      {     
     String line=null;  
      int x;        
      try              
       {

        FileReader file2 = new FileReader("nonprimes.txt");
        BufferedReader buff2=new BufferedReader(file2);

        File file1 = new File("nonprimes.txt"); 

        file1.createNewFile();      
        PrintWriter d=new PrintWriter(file1);
        while((line = buff2.readLine()) != null)    
        {
            x=Integer.parseInt(line);
            d.printf ("%d--> ", x);
            while(x%2==0)       
            {
                d.flush();
                d.print("2"+"*");
                x=x/2;
            }
            for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i = i+2)
            {
                while (x%i == 0)
                {
                    d.flush();
                    d.printf("%d*", i);
                    x = x/i;
                }
            }
            if (x > 2)
            {
            d.flush();
            d.printf ("%d ", x);
            }
            d.flush();//FLUSING THE STREAM TO FILE
            d.println("\n");

        }
        d.close();  // CLOSING FILE

    }
```

feel free to give detailed explanation. :D thanks ~anirudh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading and writing to a file in java doesnt EDIT the file, but clear the old one and creates a new one, you can use many approachesfor example, to get your data, modify it, and either save it on memory in a StringBuilder or a collection or what ever and re-write it again

well i created fileOne.txt containing the following data :

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16

and i want to multiply all those numbers by 10, then re-write them again :

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{    // just for the example

    // locate the file
    File fileOne = new File("fileOne.txt");
    FileReader inputStream = new FileReader(fileOne);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);


    // create a LinkedList to hold the data read
    List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    // prepare variables to refer to the temporary objects
    String line = null;
    int number = 0;

    // start reading
    do{
        // read each line
        line = reader.readLine();

        // check if the read data is not null, so not to use null values
        if(line != null){
            number = Integer.parseInt(line);
            numbers.add(number*10);
        }

    }while(line != null);

    // free resources
    reader.close();

    // check the new numbers before writing to file
    System.out.println("NEW NUMBERS IN MEMORY : "+numbers);

    // assign a printer
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileOne);

    // write down data
    for(int newNumber : numbers){
        writer.println(newNumber);
    }

    // free resources
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

this approach is not very good when dealing with massive data

Comment: i declared the Exception in the main method because this is about explaining, not practical life situation, you will need to handle the Exceptions when you try to use such code

Answer (score 1):

As per your problem statement, you need to take input from a file, do some processing and write back the processed data in the same file. For this, please note the below points:

- You may not create a file with same name in a directory, so you must create the new file at some other location; or write the content into different file and later rename it after deleting original one.
- While your file is open for reading, modifying the same file is not a good idea. you could use below approach:

> 1. Read the content of the file and store in a data structure liek Arrays, ArrayList.
> 2. Close the file.
> 3. Process the data stored in the data structure.
> 4. Open the file in write mode (over-write mode rather than append mode)
> 5. Write back the processed data into the file.